# Ros2 can not import python modules located in subfolders

Tags: python, ros2

I am new to use ROS. I use Ros2 Humble on Ubuntu 22.04. I need to import some python codes/modules from different nested folders (or nested nested folders) to a Ros2 python node. The Ros2 node (`demo_in_ros.py`) is located in `src` folder of my Ros package. I have all other python modules in `src` folder as well. I have imported all python modules to the Ros2 node (`demo_in_ros.py`) using the python `import` function (example: `from utils import common_utils`). The structure of my Ros2 package is below:

```
ros2demo_ws
    |src
        |dl_demo
            |dl_demo
                |demo_in_ros.py
                |utils
                    |common_utils.py
```

I have successfully built the package using `colcon build`. After running `ros2 run dl_demo pub_sub`, I get this error:

```
   from utils import common_utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

How can I solve this issue?

I appreciate any help in advance.

Thanks,

Abbas